# Delete older files but not folder in shell

Tags: shell

My code is

```
SC_PATH=/opt/shared/data/getd-cwc/tpas/tpashtmlpreview
cd $SC_PATH
logfile=$SC_PATH/logs/temp_delete.log


tpashtmlpreviewoutput=/opt/shared/data/getd-cwc/tpas/tpashtmlpreview/tpashtmlpreviewoutput

if [ -d "$tpashtmlpreviewoutput" ]
then
echo "\nChecking files-folders to delete under the directory $tpashtmlpreviewoutput" >> $logfile
find $tpashtmlpreviewoutput/* -mtime +30 -print | while read QFILENAME
do
echo "Deleting files-folders $QFILENAME " >> $logfile
#ls -lt "$QFILENAME" >> $logfile
rm -rf -- "$QFILENAME" >> $logfile
done
else
echo "Fatal error: missing directory $tpashtmlpreviewoutput" >> $logfile
fi
```

The TpasHtmlPreviewOutput has few folders like

```
gek108792
gek112110
gek114154-01
gek114154-02
gek114154-03
gek114154-10
gek114154-20
gek114154-30
```

Everytime we do a processing files get placed inside the gek folders and have the date as current date. But the GEK folder itself has a older date.

Using my above code it is deleting the gek folder also since it has date older than 30 days. But it should delete files only and not the folder inturn. The GEK folder inturn has few other folders inside.

So my basic question is "how to delete files greater than 30days and not folders older than 30days". Please help me and thanks in advance. I very much appreciate your help and time :)

Comment: Just add `-type f` to your `find` command to limit results to files?

Comment: it is working fine Thanks. Also the code is deleting logo.png file. where should i add the exception to not delete the logo.png file ? Please help.

Comment: Well, you could pipe the result of `find` through `grep -v ...`, or you could add a `! -name logo.png` condition to your `find` command.